# How do I install memorex 6142u scanner into virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, scanner, sane

I have a memorex 6142u scanner that I am trying to use on Linux. Since it isnt supported by SANE, I am going to have to use virtualbox. However I cannot install the scanner, but it is detected.

```
gaurav@Shirodkar-Inspiron-530:~$ sudo sane-find-scanner
[sudo] password for gaurav: 

# No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
# you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found USB scanner (vendor=0x0461 [Primax], product=0x0347 [USB Scanner]) at libusb:005:004
```

How do I install the scanner into virtualbox on lubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access that scanner from within the Virtual Machine. Look at the menu at the top you will see `devices` select that and go to `usb` and there you will see your connected scanner.

Click on the scanner entry and you should be fine.

[image]

Comment: I tried doing this, and the scanner does not exist in the usb settings.

Comment: Do you have guest additions installed

Comment: yes. I have the expansion pack, guest additions, and the scanner drivers installed for Windows 2000. (The guest OS I am using)

Comment: I just tested it out after 3 reboots and it randomly appeared in the menu. Thank you so much!